# Nested for loop on tupled coordinates

Tags: python, for-loop, math, coordinates, nested-loops

I need to write a code that will eventually read in coordinates from across multiple tables of big data stored in excel sheets but first I wanted to learn to write a nested for loop to analyze the tuples in the code below.

All I can find for nested for loops don't have anything like this so I thought it could be good to post up here.

What I need this code to do specifically is to take the first coordinate in file1 and compare it to each coordinate in file2, Then second coordinate in file1 to each coordinate in file2, and so on to loop through each coordinate in file1 compared to every coordinate in file to and then return if the two share the specified proximity.

```
import math
file1 = ('1.36, 7.11', '1.38, 7.12', '1.5, -7.14', '8.7, 3.33', '8.5, 3.34', '8.63, -3.36')
file2 = ('1.46, 7.31', '1.47, 7.32', '1.49, -7.34', '8.56, 3.13', '8.57, 3.14', '8.59, -3.16')
dist = file1.apply(lambda row: math.hypot(row['x_diff'], row['y_diff']), axis=1)
for dist in file1:
    for dist in file2:
        if dist.values >= .5:
            print 'no match'
        elif dist.values <= .5:
            print True, dist
```

My hunch with whats wrong is that I am not filling the appropriate command to read the tuples as coordinates. Then furthermore, I am having a lot of confusion as to what I ought to write in this statement here `for dist in file1`. By that I mean what I am supposed to call and how to label it appropriately.

I realize this is probably a mess but, this is my first coding project ever so if absolutely anybody can help steer me in the right direction or provide some feedback as to what I might need to understand better here I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The sample code does not work at all. The 4'th line fails because file1 is a tuple and no Dataframe?

Comment: @MichaelHoff Thanks, alright I clearly have no idea what I am doing so do I need to read this as a data-frame to get it to work?

Comment: Ah, sorry, this is a part of your question? The way you operate on the variable (`file1.apply`, `lambda row...`, `axis=1`) make it look like you wanted to operate on a [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) dataframe.

Comment: No you're exactly right, I had been trying to read things in through pandas with earlier tests so that's absolutely still in my code. Maybe the issue here is that I just don't know how to reformat it without pandas? Or should I transform the data through pandas to read most efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You represent your tuples as strings which is very inconvenient to work with.
"Real" tuples are generally better to start off.

```
file1 = [(1.36, 7.11), (1.38, 7.12), (1.5, -7.14), (8.7, 3.33)]
file2 = [(1.46, 7.31), (1.47, 7.32), (1.49, -7.34), (8.56, 3.13)]
```

The next question is, how do we get the distance between those two xy points?
For this, we can use `scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean` as a function which takes two tuples and returns the euclidean norm of the vector in between. For example:

```
> import scipy.spatial.distance as distance
> distance.euclidean(file1[0], file2[0])
0.22360679774997827
```

Now, we come to core of your question: the nested loop.
The logic is as follows. For each element in `file1`, say `coord1`, we take each element in `file2`, say `coord2` and compute the distance between `coord1` and `coord2`.

```
for coord1 in file1:
    for coord2 in file2:
        dist = distance.euclidean(coord1, coord2) # do not forget to import distance before
        if dist < 0.5:
            print True, dist
        else:
            print 'no match'
```

I would name the variables after what they represent. `file1` is a `coordinate_list` (`first_coordinate_list`, `coordinate_list_1`) and the elements are coordinates, e.g. `coordinate`, `coordinate_1`, `left_coordinate`.

Comment: Thanks for that, super informative. Quick question about it though: Will I need to write another for loop for each element? Just as an example would I need to write out for `coord1 in file1:`
    `for coord2n in file2:` for each coord2 in file1: or will what you have writen above take coord 1 and search a match for every coord in file 2 and then coord2 for every coord in file 2. So on down the list till eaxh coord in file1 is checked with each coord in file2?

Comment: No, you don't need a third loop. Think of it like operating with two hands. The left hand is the outer and the right hand the inner loop. You first take one single tuple of the outer list into the left hand. Then, one after the other, you take on element of the inner list into the right hand, conduct your comparison and go on. When the right hand is finished with all items, the left hand picks the next item and the right hand begins anew.

Comment: Fantastic! Also how (if I need to) do I define the coordinates as such? I'm going to take your advice in renaming file1 so it looks prettier.

Comment: As you can see in my answer representing them as `tuples` which means you put them in round parentheses can be convenient. You could also represent them using a custom class type. Numpy arrays are also a convenient representation. But for now, I suggest you to stick with the simplistic tuple format.

Answer (score 2):

**For-loops in general** :
You choose one variable as an iterator (can be anything, but shouldn't be something that is used elsewhere at the same time) which iterates through an iterable (e.g. a list). In my example below, i and j are the iterators while range(10) is the object they iterate through. Within the loop, you write everything down you want to have repeated. In my example below, I append every possible i/j combination to the list.

 
**Nested** for loops require you to use **two different variables**.

Example:

```
whatever = []
for j in range(10):
    for i in range(10):
        whatever.append([j, i])
```

After running the code, whatever will look like that:

```
[ [0, 0], [0, 1], [0,2] ,... [1, 0], [1, 1], ... [9, 9] ]
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was defining my i, j variables as file1 and file2? Do they need to be titles i and j to work properly?

Comment: @JustinT In your code you have used the name `dist` for both loop variables.  Two nested loops with a shared loop variable doesn't make sense.  The tuples file1 or file2 contain the sequences of values to be iterated over.   Each time through the loop, the loop variable is assigned a new value from the sequence.  Rafael's i, j variables correspond to your `dist`; Rafael's `range(10)` calls correspond to your file1 and file2.

Comment: @PaulCornelius Oops that is what I had meant. That makes sense then that thats the problem I am having here thank you. Any advice on how to properly call the distance to be applied to the values in file2 then or what to call it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're getting your data in as tuples:

```
# convert file1 and file2 to lists of 2d points
# this is quite sloppy and I'll tidy it up when I get home from work
xs = [[float(pq.split(',')[0]),float(pq.split(',')[1])] for pq in list(file1)]
ys = [[float(pq.split(',')[0]),float(pq.split(',')[1])] for pq in list(file2)]
# generate a cartesian product of the two lists
cp = [(x,y) for x in xs for y in ys]
# generate distances
dists = map(lambda (x,y):math.hypot(x[0]-y[0],x[1]-y[1]),cp)
# loop through and find distances below some_threshold
for i in range(len(xs)):
    for j in range(1,len(ys)+1):
        if dists[i*j] > some_threshold:
            print i,j,dist
        else:
            print 'no match'
```

I would recommend using pandas or numpy if you're going to be reading in any reasonably sized dataset, however.

Comment: Thanks for that, My code is now at least giving me no errors thanks to the code you gave me, however I am unsure if what is coming out is exactly what I am looking for it to do. I get these huge outputs, and everything seems scattered and random. I am not sure how to ask you for help here anymore though. Perhaps a second stack overflow question is in order?

Comment: The code I wrote takes all of your points and computes the distances between each pair between the lists. So if your lists are: `[p1,p2,p3]` and `[q1,q2,q3]`, it computes the distances between the pairs: `p1-q1, p1-q2,p1-q3; p2-q1,p2-q2,p2-q3; p3-q1,p3-q2,p3-q3`